# Display html with "images as http request" in React Native

Tags: html, react-native, get, request, fetch

I am working on React Natives email client for android (for special purpose - not pop/imap)

I am receiving email as htmlstring via fetch() with cookies login in this app and display it as react-native-render-html.

There are images like this:

```
<img src="../d713dae5e1920319c125865c00304b6d/Body/0.1A2C?OpenElement&amp;FieldElemFormat=gif" width="1041" height="447">
```

This img src is http GET request which returns image and this request use same cookies as returned htmlstring.

My question is: **How to call and display these images with easy way?** Hard way means parse, fetch, display(how display?) every image and I wont to do this. I can think of webview and pass cookies.

So anyone has solved before?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoa whoa I send link into react-native-webview (expo) directly and seems it uses cookie from fetch - I dont know how, but works.